# Remove Selected/Highlighted Text using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this

```
<div id="remove"></div>
<div CONTENTEDITABLE="true"></div>
```

If a user highlights text in the contenteditable div and clicks on the remove div, I would like to remove that text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accepted Answer does not work if one character gets highlighted from left to right.

I used this to remove text:

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4GP4/)

```
$("#remove").on('click', function (){
if (window.getSelection().toString() != "") {
            selectedText = window.getSelection().toString()
            var text1 = $(".selected").text().split("")
            pointStart = window.getSelection().anchorOffset
            pointEnd = window.getSelection().focusOffset

            if (pointEnd < pointStart) {
                pointStart = pointEnd
            }
            text1.splice(pointStart, selectedText.length);
            text1 = text1.join("")
        } else {
            selectedText = $(".selected").text()
            var text1 = ""
        }
    $(".selected").text(text1)
});
```

Comment: @buck54321 I know you marked this as an answer a very long time ago.. but the accepted answer will cause issues. Please review the above suggestion

Answer (score 3):

With a remove-button instead of a remove-div:

```
function removeSelectedText () {
    if (window.getSelection || document.getSelection) {
        var oSelection = (window.getSelection ? window : document).getSelection();
        $('#text').text(
            $('#text').text().substr(0, oSelection.anchorOffset)
            + $('#text').text().substr(oSelection.focusOffset)
        );
    } else {
        document.selection.clear();
    }
}

$('#remove').click(function() {
    removeSelectedText();
});
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/RUkuX/).

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to [mark the accepted answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) for all your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some content to your HTML:

```
<div id="remove"><a href="#">Remove</a></div>
<div CONTENTEDITABLE="true">Hello World! This is a test text.</div>
```

Here's the code:

```
var getSelected = function(){
  var t = '';
  if(window.getSelection){
    t = window.getSelection();
  }else if(document.getSelection){
    t = document.getSelection();
  }else if(document.selection){
    t = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  return t;
};

$('div#remove').click(function(){
    var selection = getSelected();
    var text = $('div[CONTENTEDITABLE=true]').text();
    text = text.replace(selection, '');
    $('div[CONTENTEDITABLE=true]').text(text);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SBLva/

Comment: @cratsman: 1) You should update the jsfiddle. 2.) the code will remove only the first occurrence of the higlighted text.

Answer (score 0):

make `div#remove` to `button#remove`

```
function getSelectedText() {
        return window.getSelection ? window.getSelection() // ie9 or above
                                    : document.selection.createRange().text; // earliar ie9
    }
$('#remove').click(function() {
    var curText = $('#editable').text(),
    selObj = getSelectedText(),
    selText = selObj.toString();
    var newTxt = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < curText.length; i++) {
        if (i < selObj.anchorOffset || i >= (selObj.anchorOffset + selText.length)) {
            newTxt += curText[i];
        }
    }
    $('#editable').text(newTxt);
});
```

Comment: @buck54321 yup. it prevent loss of focus

Comment: Just realized that this code will remove only the first instance of text. So if that piece of text matches text that occurs earlier in the div, the earlier text will be removed.